# ElasticBeanstalk - SQLite version is wrong, how do I fix this for my django project?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a Django Project on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I encountered a 500 error. I've traced my error to do with SQLite

```
[Sun Feb 14 20:02:02.485066 2021] [:error] [pid 419]     check_sqlite_version()
[Sun Feb 14 20:02:02.485072 2021] [:error] [pid 419]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/
sqlite3/base.py", line 67, in check_sqlite_version
[Sun Feb 14 20:02:02.485075 2021] [:error] [pid 419]     raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % D
atabase.sqlite_version)
[Sun Feb 14 20:02:02.485096 2021] [:error] [pid 419] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (fo
und 3.7.17).
```

I don't have any power to upgrade SQLLite on EB it seems. My SSH access is Read-only. How am I supposed to get Django to work in this environment?

Requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.6
Pillow==8.1.0
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

Comment: [The latest compatible version is Django 2.1 with the Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.6](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-setup-venv). SQLite is a database engine included in Python. The database is deployed with your project files.

Answer (score 1):

This took me forever to figure out so for whoever goes down this rabbit hole heres the answer:

The following are what my requirements.txt ended up being (in addition to requirement library.

```
asgiref==3.3.4
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
Django==2.1.15
idna==2.10
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
urllib3==1.26.5
```

The issue comes from django versioning, so you need to pip install django==2.1.* and then the sqlite versioning will work after you put it back into requirements through

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```